# one way ssl over jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, ssl, jboss7.x

I am trying to configure one way ssl self signed on jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.
i have created a keystore using java keytool

following is the command i have used to generate the keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias foo -keyalg RSA -keystore foo.keystore -validity 10950
```

the keystore was generated. i have alos modified the standalone.xml file

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="password" certificate-key-file="D:\Projects\Fiserv\certificate\self signed\foo.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="true"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

http wprks fine, but when i use https, i get the below error

```
Certificate-based authentication failed

Hide details
This server requires a certificate for authentication, and didn't accept the     one sent by the browser. Your certificate may have expired, or the server may not trust its issuer. You can try again with a different certificate, if you have one, or you may have to obtain a valid certificate from elsewhere.
Error code: ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set verify-client="true" to false. You have now specified that the client must also present a certificate (ie. mutual authentication). Thats also what the error code says: ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT